# Array not printing correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program in which I am reading a list of Celsius  temperatures from a file, loading them into an array, and eventually loading another array with the corresponding Fahrenheit temperatures for each Celsius temperature.

When attempting to print the fahrArray, rather than displaying actual temperatures which were converted to Fahrenheit to Celsius, I am given this

```
[D@3d3b10b1>
```

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class BonusLab {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    createdBy();

    double[] celArray = loadCelArray();

    printArray(celArray);

    double[] fahrArray = loadFahrArray(celArray);

  } // end main

  public static void createdBy() {
    System.out.println("Program created by-Beth Tanner");
  } // end createdBy

  public static double[] loadCelArray() throws IOException {
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("weather.txt"));

    int x = fin.nextInt();

    double[] celArray= new double[x];

    for(int i = 0; i < celArray.length; i++)
      celArray[i] = fin.nextDouble();

    return celArray;
  } // end loadCelArray

  public static void printArray(double[] celArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < celArray.length; i++)
    System.out.print(celArray[i] + " ");
  } // end printArray

  public static double[] loadFahrArray(double[] celArray) throws      IOException {
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("weather.txt"));

double celsius = 

int x = fin.nextInt();

double[] fahrArray = new double[x];
for(int i = 0; i < fahrArray.length; i++) 
  fahrArray[i] = (9 / 5) * celsius + 32;

return fahrArray;
  } // end loadFahrArray

} // end class
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `double celsius = ` I believe this is typo?

Comment: Please fix your formatting!

Comment: "cannot find symbol/variable (called i)" and "incomaptible types (cannot assign a double[] to a double)" - sounds clear enough

Comment: `double celsius = celArray[i]` is the right idea, but you did want to do this more than once, right, since you need to do this for every element of `celArray`?  So move it inside the `for` loop.  You will need to add curly braces.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I corrected my initial problem by declaring celsius within the for loop. Now my issue is that it is not printing the fahrArray correctly, rather than actual temperatures based on the conversion formula, it is giving me this [D@3d3b10b1> Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an `ArrayList` in preference to a bare array; it works a lot better.

Comment: I don't see the code that prints the `fahrArray`, but I'm just about positive that you are printing the array instead of the values in the array.

Comment: Wow, don't I feel stupid. Yep, that was it. I guess I must have been working on this for too long ha.

Comment: haha glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your code right, I think you should change this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < fahrArray.length; i++) 
    fahrArray[i] = (9 / 5) * celsius + 32;
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < fahrArray.length; i++) 
    fahrArray[i] = (9 / 5.0) * celArray[i] + 32;
```

You are trying to access celArray[i] at a position where i is not defined. In the for-loop i is defined and should be at the same position.

Another soluion is, that you can leave out the second scanning of the file, because u have already loaded the values. So it will be enough to loop through calArray.

Edit:
user3008950 now provided the second possibility I wrote about.

Comment: Thank you, this corrected my original problem, I have updated the question with my current issue.

Comment: it will not give you correct answer. `9/5` will always result in `1`, use `9/5.0` to get `1.8`

Comment: @Smit thats right, I just wanted to correct the code. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double[] loadFahrArray(double[] celArray){
    double[] result=null;
    if(celArray!=null){
        result=new double[celArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < celArray.length; i++){ 
            result[i] = (9 / 5.0) * celArray[i] + 32;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```